# SlideUp and SlideDown issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, slidedown, slideup, hashchange

Everything works perfectly until I select a link from the second nav menu, in which case the  tag that is used to select the class, gets a new class named active, which I believe is causing the problem to manifest itself.

The problem is that whenever you have a item selected and you click it again for it to slide up, you cant make it slide down for a second time.

http://jsfiddle.net/nBeUh/

```
    $("#nav2 a").click(function () {
if ($("div." + this.className).is(':hidden')) {
    $("div.cat").slideUp({
        duration: 600,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuint'
    }).filter("div." + this.className).slideDown({
        duration: 600,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuint'
    });
```

Would it also be possible to make the entire navigation menu inside of a single UL list and nest the other items within it, however have the secondary UL show outside of the parent?